# Recurring Folds Through A Circle

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

If I were to cut a circular disk of paper, I would have a disk with one section. If I were then to fold it through its centre, I would have a disk with two sections (divided by the crease). If I were then to fold it again through its centre but in a different place to the original folds, I would have a disk with four sections (divided by two creases) etc -> 6, 8, 10, 12 sections.

[image: Disk folding diagram]

So if the first zero case is excluded, the pattern is simple and is something along the lines of;

$$ F_n = F_{n-1} + 2, n > 1 $$
$$ F_1 = 2 $$

Which would have the closed solution;

$$ F_n = n \cdot 2, n > 1 $$

My question is, does having no folds rightfully belong in the sequence? It seems to disrupt an otherwise simple relationship.

[image]

(Number of folds on the x, regions on the disk on y)

I have a nagging feeling that disregarding what seems to be the first in a sequence feels like cheating. I have been reading 'Concrete Mathematics' after taking a level maths a few years back, and am amazed how different this kind of maths is from school maths. I suppose what I am struggling for is a logical anchor point from which to answer the following:

Is it my mistake to try and include this first point in the sequence, or does it belong and I am just unable to see the recurrence which includes it?

Really appreciate any guidance,
Thanks

Comment: You could say: A *sector* is the space between two rays emanating from the center of the disk. As such it, e.g., has a well-defined symmetry axis. Then $F_0$ contains $0$ sectors.

Comment: We can have $u_{n+1}=(u_1+1)n,\space u_1=1,\space n \in \mathbb Z^+$

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem on defining the first member of the sequence independently. Let me give you two simple examples:

- The sequence given by the [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of the integers, $a_n=n!$ for $n\ge0$, seems to be a closed form which is equal for all $n\ge0$. But, what does $n!$ mean?
  $$n!=
  \begin{cases}
  1,&n=0,\\[5pt]
  \prod_{k=1}^n k,&n\ge1.
  \end{cases}$$
  So the term $a_0$ has a particular definition.
- The (probably) most famous sequence, [Fibonnaci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), has its first TWO elements defined independently.
  $$F_0=1,\quad F_1=1,\quad F_{n} = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\text{ for }n\ge2.$$

By the way, you can find more information about your sequence in the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A004277).